# Starting a script on a CentOS VM every time the snapshot is brought up

Tags: linux, shell, centos, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a simple script on my CentOS VM. My goal is to have it run every time the snapshot is brought up. The only information I can find is regarding the running of it at boot, which I presume is not the same for bringing up a snapshot.

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately your VM will have no idea that it was rolled back to a snapshot. You could build an app/script which uses vCenter API to look for a rollback event and then triggers the relevant scripts on target guest.
That's an entirely different question though as it could be implemented in many ways.

Comment: I was thinking that it would be asking too much. Thanks for the update